# select all rows by distinct values with limit on distinct values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have 2 tables:

```
Table1:         Table2:
id | t2id       id | col
----------      ----------
1  |  1         1  |  a
2  |  2         2  |  b
3  |  2         3  |  c
4  |  1         4  |  d
5  |  3         5  |  e
6  |  3         6  |  f
7  |  4         7  |  g
8  |  5         8  |  h
9  |  1         9  |  i
10 |  4         10 |  j
```

My question is:
Is there any **short way** to put limit for distinct results of `Table1.t2id` column? 

For example: if `limit = 2` then all rows with `t2id` from 1 to 2 (or any other values) are selected.

Expected result (with `limit = 2`):

```
Res:
id | t2id
----------
1  |  1
2  |  2
3  |  2
4  |  1
9  |  1
```

#### Note:

Any information or suggestion are accepted

Answer (score 0):

You could use just the where clause

```
Select id,t2id
from table1
where t2id<=2
```

Or you can use where .. between

```
Select id,t2id
from table1
where t2id between 1 and 2
```

Comment: the problem is that i don't have predefined input. Input values as 1 or 2 from example are first encountered values from Table2

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to:

1. Create a subquery with all the columns you need + this one: `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Table1.t2id) AS MyRank`
2. outside of the sub-query, add a `where` on `MyRank`

Complete solution:

```
SELECT id, tb2id
FROM (
SELECT id, tb2id, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Table1.t2id) AS MyRank
FROM table1
) MySubQuery
WHERE MyRank <= 2
```

This will adapt to `JOIN`s with table2 (with potential multiplicity increase) and non-consecutive values in tb2id.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `in`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.t2_id in (select t2.id from table2 t2 limit 2);
```

The advantage of this approach is that it is easy to make it random:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.t2_id in (select t2.id from table2 t2 order by random() limit 2);
```